# Count greater than a number in a group by having statement?

Tags: sql

I want to see if any users have more than 6 active photos. How do I see that?

```
select user_id, count(1)
from exp_content.photos_v4
group by user_id, active
having active = True
```

That gives me data that looks like this:

```
<user_id>,6
<another_user_id>,6
<another_user_id>,6
<another_user_id>,6
<another_user_id>,6
<another_user_id>,6
<another_user_id>,6
```

How do I just get a true/false if any users have greater than 6 active photos? Or show user ids with greater than 6 active photos?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for set function conditions. Use the WHERE clause for regular (non-aggregation) conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM exp_content.photos_v4
WHERE active = True
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 6;
```

If you want to show also the number of photos:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as num_active_photos
FROM exp_content.photos_v4
WHERE active = True
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING num_active_photos > 6;
```

Comment: can I also do this: `select user_id, count(1) from exp_content.photos_v4 group by user_id, active having active = True and count(1) > 6;`

Comment: Yes you can do this:

Comment: You can play with your [query here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CYGeEuRO)